# Xamarin Forms Displaying the list of email recipients

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am fairly new to Xamarin forms & C#.

I am trying to display the list of an email recipients in a Xamarin Forms app.

Model class has:

```
public class EmailAddress3
{

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class ToRecipient
{

    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public EmailAddress3 EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MailItem
{
 ........
    [JsonProperty("toRecipients")]
    public ToRecipient[] ToRecipients { get; set; }
 .........
 }
```

C# code behind

```
 public partial class EmailDetailPage : ContentPage
 {
    public EmailDetailPage(MailItem sentMailDetail)
    {
        if (sentMailDetail == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        BindingContext = sentMailDetail;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and XAML file

```
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding CcRecipients.EmailAddress.Name}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

When I run it on a device, I keep getting the following error message:

`Binding: 'EmailAddress' property not found on 'ISPulse.Model.CcRecipient[]'`, `target property: 'Xamarin.Forms.Label.Text'`

I have tried different combinations to both the label and the Model class without any success.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: if CcRecipients is a collection (you don't show the code, so I can't be sure) then you can't bind it like that.  You have to specify which item of the collection you're referring to, like CcRecipients[0].EmailAddress.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ccRecipients is a collection, then you could bind a ListView to that collection, something like:

```
<ContentPage ... x:Name="MyPage">

    <ListView x:Name="ListviewRecipients" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ccRecipients, Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
                      VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Label Text="{Binding EmailAddress.Name}" />
    </ListView>

</ContentPage>
```

Where `MyPage` is updated to match the x:Name attribute of your root element in your XAML file. This should display a list of labels, one for each recipient in your data, with the name output to the screen.